# Why do i get a empty Tableview with these code? JSON

Tags: ios, json, parsing, tableview, swift3

i'm having some trouble with loading data into my tableview. The data doesn't seem to load properly. I'm just getting started to IOS programming, and have been stuck on this problem for a while.

[Here is a screenshot of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCk9k.jpg)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

var afspraken = [Afspraak]()

func loadJsonData()
{
    let url = URL(string: "https://i342444.venus.fhict.nl/")
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!)
    {
        (data, response, error)
        in
        if error != nil
        {
            print (error)
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
                self.parseJsonData(jsonObject as! Array<AnyObject>)
                print(data)
            }
            catch let error as NSError {print("Error parsing JSON: \(error)" )}
        }
    }

    dataTask.resume()
}

func parseJsonData(_ jsonObject: Array<AnyObject>) {
    for item in jsonObject
    {
        let afspraak =
            Afspraak(naam: item["naam"] as! String
                ,   adres: item["adres"] as! String
                ,   postcode: item["postcode"] as! String
                ,   woonplaats: item["woonplaats"] as! String
                ,   telefoonnummer: item["telefoonnummer"] as! String
                ,   email: item["email"] as! String
                ,   datum: item["datum"] as! Date
                ,   tijdstip: item["tijdstip"] as! String
                ,   omschrijving: item["omschrijving"] as! String)


        afspraken.append(afspraak)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return afspraken.count 
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let currentRow = indexPath.row
    let currentAfspraak = self.afspraken[currentRow]
    Cell.textLabel?.text = currentAfspraak.naam
    return Cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An URLDataTask Request is running in the background thread (non UI thread). Therefore you need to update the UI on the main thread using GCD-Grand Central Dispatch after completion.

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

> Edit

I took a look into your JSON URL, it is not a JSON file, it is an HTML file. That's why the `JSONSerialization` is returning invalid. You need to put the `.json` file onto your server instead of embedding json string into an HTML file.

The file on your server is like this:
[image: as you can see this is an HTML.]

as you can see this is an HTML.

The correct JSON file should be like this:
[image]

> Please notice the difference between the two URLs on top of the image, the correct one has `.json`, and yours is just /, which is a directory.

Therefore what you need to do is upload your JSON file to your server, and use the corresponding URL, like https://i342444.venus.fhict.nl/coolName.json

Comment: True, this was something I still needed to add. But the problem seems to be in loading the JSON data. My array remains empty while running the code so something is going wrong there I quess.

Comment: @DennisvdEijnde Please see my edited answer, there is a problem with your URL.